# Why doesn't pyenv virtualenv add `~.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims` to my paths?

Tags: pyenv, zshrc, pyenv-virtualenv

I'm trying to get commands to properly run inside of a repo at work which requires that I run `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` and `eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"` in my .zshrc to set paths correctly. But for some reason it's giving me `/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv-virtualenv/1.1.5/shims` instead of `~.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims`, causing commands to use local versions and build scripts not to work.

Any idea why this is happening? I checked and there isn't even a plugins folder in my pyenv. I'm at a complete loss. I'm on an M1 mac mini, but I'm using a rosetta terminal so I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the issue was that I had installed `pyenv-virtualenv` through brew instead of as a plugin. Running the following fixed the issue, as specified [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv):

```
git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv.git $(pyenv root)/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv
```